# Migrating to webpack 5 : Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, stream, migration

I have been on this bug for several days and nothing that has been written about on the internet helped me.

It occured after I migrated to webpack5 from version 4.

Here is the error:
[image]

here is where it occurs precisely:

````
     var inherits = function inherits(cls, superCtor, statics, prototype) {   // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle   cls.super_ = superCtor;
    
      if (!prototype) {
        prototype = statics;
        statics = null;   }
    
      if (statics) {
        Object.keys(statics).forEach(function (i) {
          Object.defineProperty(cls, i, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(statics, i));
        });   }
    
      var properties = {
        constructor: {
          value: cls,
          enumerable: false,
          writable: false,
          configurable: true
        }   };
    
      if (prototype) {
        Object.keys(prototype).forEach(function (i) {
          properties[i] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, i);
        });   }
    
      cls.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, properties);//here };    ```
    
    If you continue to look after who called that function :
````

```
var Stream = require('stream');

(...)

var StreamBuf = function StreamBuf(options) {
  options = options || {};
  this.bufSize = options.bufSize || 1024 * 1024;
  this.buffers = []; // batch mode fills a buffer completely before passing the data on
  // to pipes or 'readable' event listeners

  this.batch = options.batch || false;
  this.corked = false; // where in the current writable buffer we're up to

  this.inPos = 0; // where in the current readable buffer we've read up to

  this.outPos = 0; // consuming pipe streams go here

  this.pipes = []; // controls emit('data')

  this.paused = false;
  this.encoding = null;
};

utils.inherits(StreamBuf, Stream.Duplex, {
```

So the problem is supposed to be the require stream. But I installed it already.

Here is my package.json:

````
         {
  
        "start:dev": "webpack serve",
       
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "14.17.1"
      },
     
      "keywords": [
     

      "dependencies": {

        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "base64-js": "^1.5.1",
        "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
        "clipboard": "^1.6.1",
        "compression": "^1.6.2",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "^8.0.1",
        "core-js": "^3.15.1",
        "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
        "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
        "exceljs": "^1.15.0",
        "express": "^4.14.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
        "firebase": "^8.6.8",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "gsap": "^1.19.1",
        "helmet": "^3.4.0",
        "if-env": "^1.0.0",
        "ipaddr.js": "^1.9.1",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
        "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.14",
        "lodash.at": "^4.6.0",
        "marked": "^0.3.6",
        "moment": "^2.15.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
        "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^15.6.0",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^2.6.4",
        "react-datepicker": "^0.55.0",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.0",
        "react-popper": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
        "react-router": "^3.0.0",
        "readable-stream": "^2.0.2",
        "redux": "^3.5.2",
        "redux-logger": "^2.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
        "sockjs-client": "^1.1.4",
        "stream": "0`enter code here`.0.2",
        "string.prototype.endswith": "^0.2.0",
        "string.prototype.startswith": "^0.2.0",
        "tapable": "1.0.0-beta.5",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.12",
        "webfontloader": "^1.6.27",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.6.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
        "@babel/node": "^7.6.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/register": "^7.11.5",
        "app-require": "^0.1.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.0",
        "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
        "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint": "^5.16.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^9.10.0",
        "forever": "^0.15.3",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "loglevel": "^1.6.4",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
        "mocha": "^6.2.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.3",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "util": "^0.12.4",
        "webpack": "^5.40.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
      }
    }
    ```

And here is my webpack config:

```.

        const webpack = require('webpack');
    const path = require("path");
    
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
    const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
    const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
    
    const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
    
    const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"
    const simulateProd = process.env.SIMULATE_PROD
    const isProdEnv = nodeEnv === 'production'
    const isNotDevEnv = nodeEnv !== "development"
    
    const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, './dist');
    const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './src');
    const imagesPath = path.join(__dirname, './src/images');
    const iconsPath = path.join(__dirname, './src/icons');
    const soundsPath = path.join(__dirname, './src/sounds');
    
    
    // Common plugins
    const plugins = [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options: {
          postcss: [
            autoprefixer(),
          ],
          context: sourcePath,
        },
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin(
        { 
          patterns: [
            {from: iconsPath, to: 'icons'},
          {from: imagesPath, to: 'images'}
          ]
        }
      ),
      new Dotenv({
        systemvars: true
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(sourcePath, 'index.html'),
        path: buildPath,
        filename: 'index.html',
      }),
    ]
    
    
    // Common rules
    const rules = [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
        }
        // use: [
        //   'babel-loader',
        // ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              url : false
            }
          },
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|svg|mp3|html)$/,
        include: [imagesPath, soundsPath],
        use: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
    
    
    if (isProdEnv) {
      // Production plugins
      plugins.push(
        new TerserPlugin({
          cache: true,
          parallel: true,
          sourceMap: true
        })
      )
    } else {
      // Development plugins
      plugins.push(
          new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
      )
    }
    
    module.exports = {
      devtool: isNotDevEnv ? false : 'source-map',
      context: sourcePath,
      
      entry: {
        js: './index.js',
      },
      output: {
        path: buildPath,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "bundle.js",
      },
      module: {
        rules,
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack-loader.js', '.web-loader.js', '.loader.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.md', '.scss', '.css'],
        modules: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
          sourcePath,
        ],
        fallback: {
          "buffer": false,
          "fs": false,
          "os": false,
          "path": false,
          "zlib": false,
          "stream": false,
          "crypto": false,
    
        } ,
      },
      plugins,
      optimization : {
        moduleIds: 'named',
      },
      devServer: {
        contentBase: isNotDevEnv ? buildPath : sourcePath,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        port: 8080,
        compress: isNotDevEnv,
        inline: !isNotDevEnv,
        hot: !isNotDevEnv,
        host: "localhost",
        disableHostCheck: true,
        stats: {
          assets: true,
          children: false,
          chunks: false,
          hash: false,
          modules: false,
          publicPath: false,
          timings: true,
          version: false,
          warnings: true,
          colors: {
            green: '\u001b[32m',
          },
        },
      },
    };
````

I tried a lot of things with the fallbacks but without succes. Of course that I removed package.lock and node-modules and then installed but same thing. I also installed excel-js again.

I am waiting for a miracle now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`npm i exceljs@latest` (with `@latest`) fixed it